# Vuex State Object Detection in Typescript Vue

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vuex

I'm trying to create simple cart system as my first VueJS practice. I start this project from `@vue/cli` with Typescript and Vuex and class style-component. Right now, I'm stuck at state object change detection. The state is really update but my component is not re-render.

Here is my state interface. Very simple. Key is `ID` of product, Val is amount added to cart.

```
interface CartItem {
    [key: string]: number;
}
```

Here is my template

```
<template v-for="book in productLists.books">
     <div class="cart-controller">
         <button @click="addToCart(id)">-</button>                            
     </div>
     <div class="item-in-class">{{ getAmountInCart(book.id) }} In Cart</div>
</template>
```

I have only one button that use to add product to cart. Later after it added, it should update `div.item-in-class` content with number of item added to cart.

Here is my components

```
<script lang="ts">
import { Vue, Component, Watch } from 'vue-property-decorator';
import { ACTION_TYPE as CART_ACTION_TYPE } from '@/store/modules/cart/actions';
import { ACTION_TYPE as PRODUCT_ACTION_TYPE } from '@/store/modules/product/actions';

@Component
export default class BooksLists extends Vue {

    private cart = this.$store.state.cart;

    @Watch('this.cart') // try to use watch here, but look like it doesn't work
    oncartChange(newVal: any, oldVal: any){
        console.log(oldVal);
    }

    private mounted() {
        this.$store.dispatch(PRODUCT_ACTION_TYPE.FETCH_BOOKS);    
    }

    private getAmountInCart(bookId: string): void {
        return this.cart.items && this.cart.items[bookId] || 0;
    }

    private addToCart(bookId: number) {
        this.$store.dispatch(CART_ACTION_TYPE.ADD_TO_CART, bookId);
        console.log(this.cart);
    }
}
</script>
```

UPDATE 1

my action is also simple. Only receive itemId and commit to Mutation.

Action

```
const actions: ActionTree<CartState, RootState> = {
    [ACTION_TYPE.ADD_TO_CART]({ commit }, item: CartItem): void {
        commit(MUTATION_TYPE.ADD_ITEM_TO_CART, item);
    },
};
```

Mutation

```
const mutations: MutationTree<CartState> = {
    [MUTATION_TYPE.ADD_ITEM_TO_CART](state: CartState, payload: number): void {
        if (state.items[payload]) {
            state.items[payload] += 1;
            return;
        }
        state.items[payload] = 1;
    },
};
```

Comment: Please add the code of mutation ADD_TO_CART

Comment: @Riddhi thanks for reply, I already updated please have a look

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For making the change reactive you need to update it as follows:

```
tempVar = state.items
tempVar['payload'] += 1;
state.items = Object.assign({}, tempVar)
```

Or

```
Vue.$set(state.items,'payload',1)
Vue.$set(state.items,'payload',state.items['payload']+1)
```

for more details refer https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats

Comment: yes you need to do this in place of this line.state.items[payload] += 1;

Comment: I try both. the state itself update but not my components @Riddhi

Comment: Check if this is being updated by using console this.$store.state.product

Comment: it is updated, but `getAmountInCart` in my template still show `0` instead value in state

Comment: What are these variables? this.$store.state.cart.items[bookId] && this.$store.state.cart.items[bookId].amount console them .You are updating some other variable i guess